# Errors when run app on android (appcelerator titanium)

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

OS : `Mac El Capitan`

SDK: `5.2.0.GA`

Run from `CLI`

`tn --android --emulator --device-id "Google Nexus 5 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 1080x1920" --liveview`

```
[ERROR] Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzrn;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzrp;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzro;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzrl;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzrm;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/zzc;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/zza;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/Scopes;
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
[ERROR]         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
[ERROR]         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
[ERROR]         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
[ERROR]         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
[ERROR]         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
[ERROR]         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
[ERROR]         ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue from  `com.pushwoosh.module v1.2.0` module , it conflected with `ti.map v2.3.8` module .

https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-appcelerator-titanium/issues/15

**Solution** :-

> I found a workaround. I delete google-play-services.jar from Pushwoosh
>   module and it works!!!
>
> Ti.map has two libraries: google-play-services-base.jar and
>   google-play-services-map.jar

Comment: Please watch https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/MOD-1985 for progress on a final solution for conflicting jars.